# What object is this and how do I get its information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I get back when I print the parameter for an uploaded file:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006788f88 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140331-46784-1pzga6v>, @original_filename="cost_of_peace.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_image_attributes][file]\"; filename=\"cost_of_peace.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
```

What is this object? It's not a hash nor an array... And how should I get it's information? How would I return @tempfile, or @original_filename?

Answer (score 0):

The object that you get is `HTTP upload file` object, you can [see the source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6d8c070821bc846eb263b8c045ae652ebd751569/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/upload.rb#L11)

`tempfile`, `original_filename` are attr_accessor there and you can access them via

`your_upload_object.tempfile` or `your_upload_object.original_filename`